# Did Vinayak Damodar Savarkar say, “Nazism proved undeniably the saviour of Germany”?

Tags: quotes, india, nazi-germany

[The Shillong Times:](http://www.theshillongtimes.com/2016/01/29/shillong-rss-linked-to-nazism-and-fascism/)

> The greatest admirer of Hitler and Mussolini was Vinayak Damodar Savarkar, a leading RSS member who coined the term Hindutva and advocated reconversion of the converted Hindus back to Hinduism. He said in 1940 that Hitler was not a human monster because he was a Nazi. “Nazism proved undeniably the saviour of Germany”, he proudly proclaimed. Savarkar criticised Nehru’s staunch opposition to fascism teaching Pandit Nehru that Hitler knew better than him what suited Germany best. Gandhi too was derided by Hindu nationalists for opposing Nazism and fascism.
>
> The RSS might have not explicitly been anti-Semitic but Savarkar praised Hitler’s inhuman treatment of the Jews. In 1938 while supporting anti-Jewish legislation in Germany, Savarkar justified their being driven out of the country because they were minorities in that country. He recommended a similar action for Muslims in India. Today RSS’s hatred for Muslims is likened to Nazis’s hatred the Jews.

Did [Vinayak Damodar Savarkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinayak_Damodar_Savarkar) say, “Nazism proved undeniably the saviour of Germany”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinayak Damodar Savarkar Savarkar did indeed say "***Nazism proved undeniably the saviour of Germany***" in a speech he delivered to the *Akhil Bharatiya Hindu Mahasabha*, in 1940, while criticising the Indian National Congress' foreign policy:

> Churchill and Stalin and Roosevelt want to secure and maintain their mastery over the Empires they already possess. The labels masking that mastery may be different. They may call it an Empire or a democratic republic or a Soviet republic but they all are out to thrust the will and the domination of their nations by force upon other people and their territories against their own will.
>
> ... The same thing could be said about the ‘Isms’ each of them follow. Under whatever label their principles are trotted out whether as Bolshevism or Nazism or Facism or Republicanism or Parliamentarianism their armed domination over other peoples they have conquered or wish to conquer does not and cannot savour of anything else but autocratic tyranny ... We should neither hate nor love Nazists or Bolshecists or Democrats simply on the ground of any theoretical or bookish reasons. **There is no reason to suppose that Hitler must be a human monster because he passes off as a Nazi or Churchill is a demi-God because he calls himself a Democrat. Nazism proved undeniably the saviour of Germany under the set of circumstances Germany was placed in, Bolshevism might have suited Russia very well and we know what the English Democracy has cost us.**

**Note**: *Even as he made this speech, he was working with the British imperialists - Savarkar's political history (like the speech above) shows that he was a political opportunist who would say anything to benefit his political position. That is why his admirers can claim that he didn't support Hitler or the Nazis. Nevertheless, it is very clear from his writings and speeches that he did indeed draw inspiration from Hitler's political ideas and the Nazi ideology. In 1944, he unabashedly suggested that "[Muslims should be treated like negroes](https://www.dailyo.in/politics/tom-treanor-vd-savarkar-mahatma-gandhi-hitler-nationalist-hindu-mahasabha-20207)".)*

**References**:

1. [Islam, Shamsul. RSS Primer: Based on Rashtriya Swayamsevak Sangh Documents. India: Pharos Media & Publishing, 2010.](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/RSS_Primer/Gx5R9D_JpQEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover&dq=Nazism%20proved%20undeniably%20the%20saviour%20of%20Germany)
2. [Savarkar, Vinayak Damodar. Hindu Rashtra Darshan. India: Veer Savarkar Prakashan, 1984.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hindu_Rashtra_Darshan/kFJuAAAAMAAJ).